# Sometimes bridge configured in network/interfaces does try to get a DHCP lease on bootup or after

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have the attached /etc/network/interfaces file. this works 90% of the time, but sometimes, the bridge fails to get an IP on bootup, and does not ever get a lease after that point. There must be a race condition here, but where?

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
  pre-up openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
  post-up ip link set tap0 address 70:85:cc:22:73:ae

allow-hotplug enp1s0
  iface enp1s0 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports enp1s0 tap0
  post-up ip link set br0 address 70:85:cc:22:ae:ae
```

Comment: You'd better change the mac addresses before the interface is up rather than after it's up.

Comment: other method: enslave tap0 only: 1st enslaved sets the bridge's mac address (unless bridge has an explicit mac address set before). then as a post-up enslave the remaining interface. Or maybe just change their order. As this needs testing by trial and error, I'm just leaving these comments.

Comment: @A.B This is an interesting point about the mac address! I wonder if this is causing issues elsewhere.